# Display Acts_as_taggable Tags seperatly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to Display each `Tag` a `Question` has in a Span. I use [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).

I managed to get the below Code working, but it's a Tag cloud. Meaning that ALL the tags are displayed.

```
<% tag_cloud Question.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
    <span class="label label-default">
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: "css_class" %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
```

To retrieve the Tags:

```
question.tag_list
```

Can someone help me refactor that code so only the CURRENT TAGS ON THE QUESTION are shown ?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37968/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18989790-display-acts-as-taggable-tags-seperat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`question.tag_list` will return you a string, and you can not loop through it.

`question.tags` will return an array,

```
<% question.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <span class="label label-default">
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: "css_class" %>
    </span>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the plugin, but one problem I see in your code-snippet in general is that you are not operating on a specific object `@question`, but on the class `Question`. If I had to take a guess, I would say that this is the source of your problem.

Edit:

So, I just checked out the documentation for the gem and I found this code-snippet directly there:

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, this is pretty much what I just told you. Instead of working on the class you have to work on a specific object or, like in the shown case, a collection of objects.

Comment: Hey, that's the specific code for a Tag Cloud. It works just fine. I'm struggling on how to display an array of hashes, each one separately.
<% question.tag_list each do %> something like that..